# doctrine relations best way

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine to my API REST that returns entities with large relations and large info. I'm trying to improve my doctrine queries performance and I have a big question. Is better to write relations with dbal queries or with XToX doctrine relations?

Thanks

Comment: It is not a matter of writing one or the other, you need your doctrine relations to be able to write your doctrine queries.

Comment: But you may avoid write doctrine relations and do the joins by yourself

Comment: Yes you can, but then you don't write relations, you do joins. It isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

My advice use OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany etc. relations. Cause when you use that relations, everything will be faster on ORM level.

Comment: Do you have any source?